# How to filter month and year from datatable "Date" column and get matching filter rows in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

In my application I need to filter all matching records from date column in datatable

```
DataRow[] dr= dt.Select(
                "date where date='" + 
                Convert.ToString(txtmonth.Text) + "' and '" +
                Convert.ToString(txtyear.Text) + "'");
```

Here I'm getting error how can I filter based on month and year from datatable date column

Comment: What is the error? And do not use string concatenation. Susceptible for sql injections.. Also conciser changing the schema to save date as a date and not as separate strings

Comment: Here my `date` column data like `01/24/2017` here when user enter `txtmonth and txtyear` only  i need to filter matching rows based on that month and year column rows count

Answer (score 1):

```
int Month = Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text).Month;
int Year= Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text).Year;

 var Query = from row in dt.AsEnumerable() //List
                       let date = row.Field<DateTime>("date")
                       where date.Month == Month && date.Year == Year
                       select row;
    DataRow[] dr = Query.ToArray();
```

Comment: post to me  details actually what you want?